# TomEE Intellij Idea: Remote deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I trying to deply my webapp on the remote server (VPS) using IDEA.

I done the following:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

And now it's fine, "Connected to server"

But then I got exception:

> [2014-11-10 03:00:44,431] Artifact MavenChat:war:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application
>   exception; nested exception is:
>
> org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/denis/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1/bin/C:\Users\Denis\IdeaProjects\MavenChat\target\MavenChat.war
>   (No such file or directory)

How can I fix it?

When I manually deploy my app, I

1. Built MavenChat.war
2. Rename it to ROOT.war
3. Upload it to /home/denis/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1/webapps

IDEA configuration screen:

[image]

I'm sure I done it wrong "Staging"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could not configure it, but I can deploy my app to my remote server using maven!
I followed [this manual](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html) and it works!